# How to Do full copy from Slice?

Tags: javascript

I an array like this

```
@observable data = [{a: 1}, {b: 1}, {c:1}];
 @observable sampleData = [];
```

I want to do a slice

```
 this.sampleData = this.data .slice(0, 1);
 this.sampleData[0].a = 2;
```

I want "2" to effect the the record in "sampleData" not in the "data" array what is happening now.

Comment: What's happening to this post? I see no reason for down votes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So you basically want to create a copy of every sliced element. You can do it like this:

```
this.sampleData = this.data.slice(0, 1).map(obj => ({ ...obj }))
```

Or using `Object.assign`:

```
this.sampleData = this.data.slice(0, 1).map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj))
```

Be advised that this is only a *shallow* copy, so if your object has nested structure, you would have to perform a *deep* copy instead.